# Powershell fails to resolve ParameterSetName when using pipes

Tags: powershell

I have a cmdlet, with a couple of ParameterSetNames. Everything works as expected, until I use pipes. The code (simplified) is as follows

```
function Test 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param(    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [string]$name,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = "Set1")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = "Set2")]
    [string] $P1,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ParameterSetName = "Set2")]
    [string] $P2
    )

    Write-Output ($name + " - " + $PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
}
```

This function works as expected for the following calls `Test aaa -P1 x`, `Test aaa -P1 x -P2 y` and (piped) `Get-ChildItem c:\Temp  | select -ExpandProperty Name | select -First 1 | Test -P1 x -P2 y`. However it fails when I try calling it piped with "Set1" `Get-ChildItem c:\Temp  | select -ExpandProperty Name | select -First 1 | Test -P1 x` it fails with an error `Dotnet-File-Quickstart - Set2
Test : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters`.

I know about setting `DefaultParameterNameSet`, but as my cmdlet is more complex than this example, that wouldn't help me.

Comment: Seems like a bug. If you assign, Set1 and Set2 directly to `name`, then it works as expected. It's as if the pipe is not respecting the AllParameterSets value.

Comment: [1] shouldn't there be a default parameter set listed? [2] shouldn't ALL the "from pipeline" parameters SAY they accept pipeline input?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey [1] Why should I need to specify a default parameter set? [2] Only the first parameter `$name` accepts values from the pipeline

Comment: @DavidSchuldenfrei - [1] default parameter set -- perhaps i misunderstood, but i thot that you were supposed to declare a default parameter set whenever you have more than one. [2] pipeline input -- my apologies, i misread your code. [*blush*]